# Django create queryset or list of unique items in multiple manytomany instances

Tags: python, django

I have a `QuestionSet` that is a manytomany of questions. Each `QuestionSet` has multiple `questions` associated with it.

I want to get a list of all unique `questions` that are in two (or more) `QuestionSets`

For example:

```
First QuestionSet = Questions(1,2,3)
Second QuestionSet = Questions(1,3,4)

Output:
List/Queryset/Something of Questions(1,2,3,4)
```

`models.py`

```
class QuestionSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)


class Question(models.Model):
    question_num = models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
questions = Question.objects.annotate(question_set_count=Count('questionset')).filter(question_set_count__gte=2)
```

You can find that more in the docs: [Django aggregates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset)